# Convert Minutes to Seconds

Tags: javascript, excel

I have a spreadsheet with values as follows:

1:29.460

I need to convert it to

89.460

I have a huge amount of these play offsets. I can either do it in excel or perhaps using javascript.

Any advice on a formula appreciated!

Comment: How are you going to feed Excel to javascript? Did you mean VBA?

Comment: You can use Excel macro for this I think. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/about-macros-in-excel-HP005201201.aspx 

First get time values (1:29.460 etc) using regexp. then split that by : to get minutes part and seconds part. Then the you can get required result by ((minutes * 60) + seconds).

Answer (score 9):

Here’s a JavaScript solution:

```
function convert(input) {
    var parts = input.split(':'),
        minutes = +parts[0],
        seconds = +parts[1];
    return (minutes * 60 + seconds).toFixed(3);
}

convert('1:29.460'); // '89.460'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use code like this:

```js
function toSeconds(str) {
    var pieces = str.split(":");
    var result = Number(pieces[0]) * 60 + Number(pieces[1]);
    return(result.toFixed(3));
}

console.log(toSeconds("1:29.460"));   // returns 89.460
```

Answer (score 1):

To give the whole picture, here is the VBA (UDF) solution:

```
Public Function ConvertToSecond(r As Range)
Dim arr As Variant, lMinutes As Long, lSeconds As Double
Debug.Print (r.Value)
arr = Split(r.Value, ":")
lMinutes = arr(0)
lSeconds = CDbl(Replace(arr(1), ".", ","))
ConvertToSecond = Format(lMinutes * 60 + lSeconds, "#0.0##")
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly formatting your cells, excel is storing your information as hh:mm.

You should add the hour column into your cell like so: `0:1:29.460` and make sure it is set to the time format.

Then in another column make sure the cell format is set to number and add the following formula (assuming your time is stored in the cell A1):

```
=A1*24*60*60
```

Comment: Because of the . Excel knows that 1:29.460 is 1 minute 29.46 seconds (unlike 1:29 which would be interpreted as 1 hour 29 mins), so =A1*86400 should work without any re-formatting.....or if the data is a real time value you can custom format as [s].000 for display of 89.460

Answer (score 0):

Write following function in your VBA Modules

```
Public Function FormatMinutes(ByVal stime) As String
    Dim hour: hour = Mid(stime, 1, InStr(1, stime, ":") - 1)
    Dim minute: minute = CInt(Mid(stime, InStr(1, stime, ":") + 1, InStr(1, stime, ".") - InStr(1, stime, ":") - 1))
    FormatMinutes = (hour * 60 + minute) & Mid(stime, InStr(1, stime, "."), Len(stime))
End Function
```

To use it, just put `=FormatMinute(A1)` in formular.